# Is comment fields data store in render array?

Tags: nodes, entities

Is render array contain key-value entries that is generated by node module **only**? or comments fields also included?

Answer (score 1):

The render array for a node contains also the content of the comments, which is added by [comment_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_node_view/7), an implementation of [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7). That hook is invoked from [node_build_content()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_build_content/7), which is called from [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7).

The Devel module shows the following output for a node render array.

[image: screenshot]

In Drupal 8, [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/8) is a thin wrapper for [entity_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_view/8), which renders the node using [entity_render_controller()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_render_controller/8).